# ImportError and project structure

Tags: python, python-import

I'm having a hard time o understand how python works with packages and modules and would really need some help here.

At first I had a project that looked like this in pycharm:

```
PROJECTNAME 
 - package1
      - __init__.py
      - MyModule.py
      - MyModule2.py
 - package2
      - __init__.py
      - MyModule3.py
 - test
      - test.py
 - RunModule.py
 - README.md
 - setup.py
```

RunModule import from module 1,2 and 3. I can run it like this without any problem:

```
python RunModule.py
```

Then I changed the structure to this:

```
PROJECTNAME 
 -projectname
      - package1
          - __init__.py
          - MyModule.py
          - MyModule2.py
       - package2
          - __init__.py
          - MyModule3.py
       - test
          - test.py
       - RunModule.py
 - README.md
 - setup.py
```

And when I try to run RunModule.py I get "ImportError: No module named projectname.package1.MyModule" and same error for all the other modules too. I know two ways to fix this:

- remove projectname in all imports in all files so it's just package1.modulename
- move RunModule.py up on directory again

If I do the first one pycharm complains when I run my tests and the second one is pretty ugly. So can I fix this in some other way?

Comment: you need to set [python path](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html) to the root of the PROJECTNAME. Then it'll recognise absolute imports with the "projectname" as first module.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the best way to do it. When I call my script from terminal I use:

```
python -m projectname.RunModule
```